# Git conflict markers appearing in a diff without being previously committed

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

A colleague has just pushed the results of their efforts to rebase/merge two branches (which they admit they struggled with) up to github. Here's a bit of the diff (mildly redacted):

```
diff --git a/portal/settings.py b/portal/settings.py
index 17c5f3e..e416be9 100644
--- a/portal/settings.py
+++ b/portal/settings.py
@@ -61,14 +61,7 @@ SEARCH_FORM_FIELDS = {
         'DEFAULT_COLUMNS': [
             ('messageurl__id', True, True),
             ('messageurl__message_url', True, False),
-<<<<<<< 8e91d650bf61b6f5a6ee187356be5591a2c3d187
-<<<<<<< 606b67c41b35fbb57823d248755503090ca3de51
             ('messageurl__time_analyzed', True, False),
-=======
->>>>>>> Added search form for URL searching
-=======
-            ('messageurl__time_analyzed', True, False),
->>>>>>> Tidied up the URL search result page
         ],
         'ES_TEXTFIELDS': ['messageurl__message_url'],
```

Just from looking at that diff, you'd assume that the previous commit included the above git conflict markers, and that this commit was removing them. However, no previous commits that I can see have those markers in them, and my colleague assures me that they didn't commit files that had merge conflicts.

How could this have happened? I've always assumed that for a git diff to show a line of text being removed, that line would have to have been present in a previous commit in the repository.

Assuming there is some weird magic that could have caused this, is there any risk that the repo is corrupted in some way? (`git fsck --full` shows no issues.)

Comment: Not only is there a conflict marker in `17c5f3e`, it's actually a double/nested marker. Try `git show 17c5f3e` to view the file and look near line 61. (Note: the magic number `17c5f3e` comes from the `Index:` line; it represents the hash ID of the `a/` file.)

Comment: `git show 17c5f3e` does indeed show the file with the conflict markers. And I've since found an earlier commit (with an unrelated commit message) that added the outer set of conflict markers to that file.

Answer (score 0):

> my colleague assures me that they didn't commit files that had merge conflicts.

I think if I had included the word "knowingly" in there it would be a true statement. :p

Thanks to torek's tip, I found the revisions that added the git conflict markers.  So I was mistaken when I thought they hadn't been present in the repo, so that mystery's solved. As a result, there's no reason for me to think the repo is corrupted.

(Incidentally, although I only showed one example of these conflict markers in one file, they were actually in 24 files, and in one case, nested 5 levels deep. I'm a bit curious about how my colleague managed to do this, but I'm also a scared to ask...)